# Fscanf from .txt in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have to `scanf` e.g. this line of text from `.txt` file (upload is correct):

```
[1,1] v=5 s=4#o`
```

And this is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int red2[10];
    int stupac2[10];
    int visina[10];
    int sirina[10];
    char boja[10];

} Tunel;
```

```
FILE *fin = fopen("farbanje.txt", "r");
Tunel *tuneli = (Tunel *)malloc(sizeof(Tunel) * 200);

int p = 0;

while (fscanf(fin, " [%d,%d]", &tuneli[p].red2, tuneli[p].stupac2) == 2)
{
    printf("%d %d", tuneli[p].red2, tuneli[p].stupac2);
    p++;
}
```

I wanted to check only 2 parameters from `.txt` but it gives me some random values.

Comment: `red2` and `stupac2` are arrays, not `int`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (fscanf(fin, " [%d,%d]", &tuneli[p].red2, tuneli[p].stupac2) == 2)
```

Is wrong, the member variables of the struct are arrays and you need to pass them to `scanf` as such, for example:

```
while (fscanf(fin, " [%d,%d]", &tuneli[p].red2[0], &tuneli[p].stupac2[0]) == 2)
```

Or make the member variables single `int`s.

The same with `printf`:

```
printf("%d %d", tuneli[p].red2[0], tuneli[p].stupac2[0]);
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CHjQngrZX5PFEGN2)